# Flutter get value from hidden textformfield similar like html input hidden

Tags: flutter

On HTML, We usually use `<input type='hidden' id='get' value='abc'/>`

Now I tried to implement on flutter.

```
Visibility(
visible: false,
child: TextFormField(
  controller: glControllerMask,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    filled: true,
    hintText: 'Garis Lintang',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Color(0xFFc0c0c0).withOpacity(1)),
  ),
  style:
      TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Color(0xFF5E5E5E)),
),
),
```

I'm using `visibility: false`, but seems not working. There is no error show.

What I need is to get the value from hidden textformfield.
Is it possible?

Comment: I think your code is okay if you didn't want to show TextFormField. It seems like other problems. please share more code.

Comment: Hi... Yes, it's not show. But how to keep get the value from `controller: glControllerMask` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value outside from textformfield

```
//initialize 
glControllerMask = TextEdittingController(text: "");

print(glControllerMask.text);
```

Comment: Just now tried, if not wrap with `Visibility`, I can see the value `print(glControllerMask.text)`. But if I wrap with `Visibility`, not show anything value

Comment: you don't get the value from the textfield `onchange` if you use `Visibility ` false

Comment: So any idea how to handle this? Or is there any other function can handle the hidden value?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you just have to set `maintainState` to `true` within the Visibility widget.

```
Visibility(
    visible: false,
    maintainState: true, //This line does the trick
    child: TextFormField(),
)
```